A question about rudin 9.32 Why $PA=A$

9.32 Theorem: Suppose ,, are nonnegative integers, $≥$,$≥$,$$   is a $^{1}$ mapping of an open set ⊂$^{}$ into $^{}$, and $′()$ has rank $r$ for every $∈$.
Fix $∈$, put $=′()$, Let $_{1}$ be the range of $A$, and let $$ be the projection in $^{}$ whose range if $_{1}$. Let $_{2}$ be the null space of $$.
Then there are open sets $$ and $$ in $^{}$, with $∈$,$⊂$ and there is a 1-1 mapping $$ of $$ onto $$(whose inverse is also of class $^{1}$) such that
$$(())=+()   (∈) $$ where $$ is a $^{1}$ mapping of open set $()⊂_{1}$ into $_{2}$.

In the proof it is stated that $PA=A$ but I don't know why

$P$ is the projection onto $Y_1$. Therefore $P|_{Y_1} = I$ (the identity). Now
$$PA = P|_{Y_1}A = I A = A,$$
because $Y_1$ is, by definition, the range of $A$.
